# KnockoutJS PubSub and save to database

Tags: knockout.js, publish-subscribe

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/8FMPc/light/) excellent tutorial and I have modified it to load data from a database using REST and now I need to save it back but stuck on where to do this/how to get the values out.

Would I do the saving in `self.editFruit = function (fruit) {` after `fruit.beginEdit(self.editTransaction);` ? in FireBug I set a breakpoint on the fruit object but can't see the properties, i.e do something like `var name = fruit.name` but if I put name in an alert I just see a function, no property.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused about how you are trying to save, but to see the name in the alert you must unwrap the property.

```
var x = fruit.name();
```

or depending on how your vm is set

```
var x = fruit().name();
```

Comment: I haven't got to the stage of saving yet, can't even manage to read the properties :s, where would you add that line in the jsfiddle?

Comment: What jsdiddle?? I did not see one in your post, and also, you get the values of observables my using it like a function ().  Add parentheses to the end of properties

Comment: I would also suggest you spend some time on knockoutjs.com to brush up on the basics before you try to build a knockout app.  There alot to it

Comment: third word in my post is a link, not sure how you could answer without looking at it, much of my post couldn't have made sense :D